# Tire elasticsearch automatically index a record with a hash in the mapping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, hash, elasticsearch, tire

I am struggling with a Tire issue.

In my Model, I added in the mapping:

`indexes :localized_title, :as => "localized_title"`

and the function that returns the hash of translations

```
def localized_title
  hash = {}
  translations.each do |t|
    hash[t.locale] = t.title
   end
  hash
end
```

When I create a record of this model, even though the record is created in the database, it is not indexed

```
>Model.search{query{all}}.total
=> 0
```

But, if I update the index manually, it is indexed.

```
>Model.last.update_index
>Model.search{query{all}}.total 
=> 1
```

An after_save update_index does not help. Any ideas ?

I would like the record to be automatically indexed, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the type of 'object' in the mapping of your localized_title, as it's a hash.

You can use

```
indexes :localized_title, :as => "localized_title", :type => :object
```